# Android - Is there any Event which fires only when Application is minimized/maximized

Tags: java, android

I am developing an application in Android which has several Activities and need to check some details only when application is minimized and maximized, not on Activity screens' navigation. `onPause()` and `onResume()` doesn't work. `onWindowFocusChanged()` also doesn't helped as that is also calling while navigating among screens. Please help in which way I can be able to get an event only when Application is minimized/maximized, not on screen navigation.

Comment: what do you mean by minimize/maximize ? Give an example please.

Comment: You are probably looking for BroadCastListeners

Comment: I think you're looking for `onStop()` and `onRestart()`

Comment: "need to check some details only when application is minimized and maximized, not on Activity screens' navigation" -- that is generally a code smell. Please explain what you think needs to be handled this way, so we can suggest alternative approaches.

Comment: Minimize/Maximize meaning, Minimize = On click of Home button, Application goes to background. Maximize = On Long Press of Home button, Task Manager will be shown. Then my application will shows up in the list. On click of application icon, last recent activity will be shown up. How to get those two events? In ios, there are pre-defined methods for these events. Does Android had the same events?

Comment: The short of it is no, Android does not have the same events, and any solution to the problem is likely to be brittle. Would you please explain what you're trying to do (as CommonsWare asked a bit earlier) so that we may try to help you solve it in an Android appropriate fashion? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not something which is common on Android, so I would agree to [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware), that you should consider a different approach.

Nevertheless, there is a (bit hacky) way to achieve this. 
Override `onStop()` and `onResume()` in every of your activities, set a `boolean` to `true` in `onResume()` and to `false` in `onStop()`. If this is `true`, the application is active, if it's `false` it's not. 
You could use a listener, which is always called after the `boolean` value is set, to execute your actions.

Comment: But, i think its a tedious job as i have numerous activities. Is any other workaround? I hope it will be there because in ios, there are methods which only works on minimize/maximize/force stopping the application. As always, Android Dev document left some things for developers to decide in cases like this.

Comment: Unfortunately not, because iOS and Android are different in terms of lifecycles. What do you want to achieve, maybe there is a better way.

Comment: This does not work on my Android 9 OnePlus, I get newActivity.onResume() before oldActivity.onStop().

Answer (score 1):

I think that this [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) callback [onUserLeaveHint()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint%28%29) could be a start.

from the doc:

> Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is about to
>   go into the background as the result of user choice. For example, when
>   the user presses the Home key, onUserLeaveHint() will be called, but
>   when an incoming phone call causes the in-call Activity to be
>   automatically brought to the foreground, onUserLeaveHint() will not be
>   called on the activity being interrupted. In cases when it is invoked,
>   this method is called right before the activity's onPause() callback.
>
> This callback and onUserInteraction() are intended to help activities
>   manage status bar notifications intelligently; specifically, for
>   helping activities determine the proper time to cancel a notfication.

Comment: Your approach works only while minimizing the application and not in Maximize. Can i have any other method on Maximize same as `onUserLeaveHint`?

Comment: not that i know of. I specifically said that can be a start cause it actually does not answear your question completly. You could try to keep track if that callback has been called or not with a boolean. But that doesn't convince me too much. :\

Comment: Does not work on Android 9 for this purpose, I get onUserLeaveHint on navigation to another activity in app

Answer (score -2):

If you can add a property, let's name it isShown in your customized Application object, which means you need extend the application for this purpose. it is in your subclass of Application and it is a signleton.

Be realized the lifecycle methods for **onPause** and **onResume**, when the **onPause** is called, it means the activity would be going to background, invisible any more, or put into the the activity stack. **onResume** means the activty status is recovered and ready for the user's interaction. So if you set the isShown property to false, which is in your application object, within the activity's **onPause**, and set it back to true in your **onResume**. of cause, you can make this behavior to be extracted into a superclass for the reuse purpose.

with the composite of **onPause** and **onResume**, and a given time we can identify the min/maxmized status. Let's say, isShown is set to false for a while, we can say it is minimized. otherwise, we can explain the maximized too.

But what are you going to do with this flag? did you still have a Service running in backend ready to receive this property to do something?

Comment: Nope. onPause and onResume is also called, when you lock the phone. Also it would only apply to a single activity.

Comment: @Leandros, ya, it will. What is your question?

Comment: It doesn't answer the question.